# How to wait till the google maps API has loaded before loading a google.maps.OverlayView derived class

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a separate label.js file in which I have defined a custom overlay. It uses the google.maps.OverlayView as its prototype:

```
Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

I am not sure where to place the script tags for this js file in my index.html file. If I place the script tags below the google maps loading tag like so:

```
....
        <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?...
        </script>
        <script src="js/label.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The label.js file is loaded immediately while the maps api has not yet loaded causing an error.

I currently solve this by manually loading the JS in my maps loaded callback:

```
function initMap() {
    gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(strMapDivName), {
        center: {lat: 21, lng: 78},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        zoom: 6,
        heading: 90,
        tilt: 0
    });

    // Load label.js afterwards so we can be sure that the google maps api has loaded
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", "js/label.js")

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)

}
```

Is this the best way to solve this?

Comment: I would say it's the best way when you load the maps-API asynchronously

Answer (score 7):

You should include a callback function in the API call.

```
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&loading=async&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

You can then include any maps related code within the callback function:

```
function initMap() {
  // Your Google Maps related code here
}
```

If you need to wait until the map is "ready" ie, the map is displayed with the map options and "idle" you can use:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
    // map is ready
});
```

But you should still include this within the callback function.

#### Edit 2024

Google now recommends [various other methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api?hl=en) for loading the API but direct script loading tag is still supported.

##### Direct script loading tag

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
    zoom: 4
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&loading=async&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

##### Or, with Dynamic Library Import API:

```js
let map;

// initMap is now async
async function initMap() {

    // Request libraries when needed, not in the script tag.
    const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    
    // Short namespaces can be used.
    map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
        zoom: 4
    });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk",
    v: "weekly",
    // Use the 'v' parameter to indicate the version to use (weekly, beta, alpha, etc.).
    // Add other bootstrap parameters as needed, using camel case.
  });
</script>
```

Of course, replace the API key with your own.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's too late, but I use this code below

```
var mapWaitCount = 0;
var mapWaitMax = 5;

function map_load(param1, param2, ...) { // if you need any param
    mapWaitCount++;
    // if api is loaded
    if(typeof google != 'undefined') {
        // your code here 
    }
    // try again if until maximum allowed attempt
    else if(mapWaitCount < mapWaitMax) {
        console.log('Waiting attempt #' + mapWaitCount); // just log
        setTimeout(function() { map_load(); }, 1000);
    }
    // if failed after maximum attempt, not mandatory
    else if(mapWaitCount >= mapWaitMax) {
        console.log('Failed to load google api');
    }
}

map_load(param1, param2, ...) { // if you need any param
```

It uses timeout to wait for the load, and after several attempts it will be stopped

Comment: I think yours is the most reliable solution, however I would change `else if(mapWaitCount < mapWaitMax)` in `else if(mapWaitCount <= mapWaitMax)` and the last else in just `>` instead of `>=`, since if you increase counter at start, it will just try 4 times, not 5 :)

Answer (score 1):

Updating an old question; in React I used the NPM module: [load-google-maps-api](https://github.com/yuanqing/load-google-maps-api#usage)

I started barking down the tree of creating that myself, before realising this existed and could save some time.

It's going to load the maps API in a promise format and so you can provide a callback function for after load.

```
loadGoogleMapsApi().then(function (googleMaps) {
  new googleMaps.Map(document.querySelector('.map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.7484405,
      lng: -73.9944191
    },
    zoom: 12
  })
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### Typescript way of doing

You can now use the [Google Maps JavaScript API Loader library](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader)

1. run `npm i @googlemaps/js-api-loader`
2. Use the loader

```js
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "",
  version: "weekly"
});
```

#### JavaScript way

3. Subscribe to the loader promise

```js
loader
  .load()
  .then((google) => {
    new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // do something
  });
```

#### Libraries way *Ex: angular*

3. Subscribe to the loader promise

```js
isMapApiLoaded?: boolean

loader
  .load()
  .then((google) => {
     this.isMapApiLoaded = true
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // do something
  });
```

4. Show the map only when loaded

```html
<google-map *ngIf="isMapApiLoaded"> 
  <!-- ... -->
</google-map>
```

#### Additional (singleton)

5. You could use the loader in a service that you then import globally

```js
export class MapLoaderService {
  onMapApiDidLoad$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(null)
  
  private _initLoader() {
    this.mapLoader
      .load()
      .then((google) => {
        this.onMapApiDidLoad$.next(true)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this.onMapApiDidLoad$.next(false)
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic that I made and works for me.

1) Define the function you want to execute after Google maps is loaded

```
function ToExecuteAfterLoaded()
  {
  // Doing something here ///
  console.log("Executing this function"); // per example //
  }
```

2) Waiting function

```
function WhenGoogleLoadedDo(fnt)
   {
   if(typeof google != 'undefined')
      fnt();
   else
      setTimeout(function()
         {(function(fnt)
            {
            WhenGoogleLoadedDo(fnt)
            })(fnt)}, 500); // You can set timer as you wish //
   }
```

3) Call the ToExecuteAfterLoaded like this in your script

```
WhenGoogleLoadedDo(ToExecuteAfterLoaded);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping your custom label with DOMContentLoaded?

```
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
      });
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Not good. Async is not guaranteed to run before domcontentloaded. Only defer is.